# Displaying XML in a web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to display the content of an XML file in a web page (as XML), in a richer experience than just plain text. Many browsers provide this by default if the mime type of the response is XML. However, the mime type is HTML and the XML is included in the response, and I can not access it from another URL, thus displaying the XML in an iframe.

I want to color nodes and attributes, display line numbers and collapse and expand nodes.

Are there any plugins for such a thing, or do I have to start from scratch here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Syntax Highlighter.  Here's a list of 11 to choose from:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-syntax-highlighters-to-beautify-code-presentation/

Comment: Yep, that one happens to be my personal favorite.